# Extracting and removing URL from a block of text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this block of text:

```
$text = 'This just happened outside the store http://somedomain.com/2012/12/store there might be more text afterwards...';
```

It needs to be converted to:

```
$result['text_1'] = 'This just happened outside the store';
$result['text_2'] = 'there might be more text afterwards...';
$result['url'] = 'http://somedomain.com/2012/12/store';
```

This is my current code, it does detect the url, but i can only remove it from the text, I still need the url value separately in an array:

```
$string = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+/', '', $text);
//returns "This just happened outside the store  there might be more text afterwards..."
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Temporal solution** (can this be optimized?)

```
$text = 'This just happened outside the store http://somedomain.com/2012/12/store There might be more text afterwards...';
preg_match('/https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+/',$text,$url);
$string = preg_split('/https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+/', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/','. ',implode(' ',$string));
echo '<a href="'.$url[0].'">'.$text.'</a>';
```

Comment: [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) and [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) are for extracting. Do your replacement afterwards. (Or actually, `preg_replace_callback()` to do all at once.)

Comment: thanks for the tip, i updated the original post with your suggestion, it is working fine now. do you think it could be optimized?

Comment: between freejosh and i the one-liner is below

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it to store in a variable or just need it inside the ahref?
How about this?

```
<?php
$text = 'This just happened outside the store http://somedomain.com/2012/12/store There might be more text afterwards...';
$pattern = '@(.*?)(https?://.*?) (.*)@';
$ret = preg_replace( $pattern, '<a href="$2">$3</a>', $text );
var_dump( $ret );
```

$1, $2, and $3 corresponds to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd parenthesis

the output would be

```
<a href="http://somedomain.com/2012/12/store">There might be more text afterwards...</a>
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty nice solution-- i'm just wondering what would happen if by any chance the block of text contains more than one link.

Comment: then that means its gonna be included inside the <a too, so should still work. but do try it out with different test cases.
You can change the 3rd parenthesis (.*) into (.*?) to make it greedy.

Answer (score 1):

you could split your string on the regex using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to give you an array

```
$result = preg_split('/(https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+)/', $the_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
// $result[0] = preamble
// $result[1] = url
// $result[2] = possible afters
```

Comment: it is not returning the url, only the text blocks. Any ideas?

Comment: You also need to set the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE flag, and wrap the regex in `()` to return it in the results.

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns an array with two items, before and after the url

Comment: I updated the post with a few new tweaks, kind of works fine. Any ideas on how to improve it?